# Detect GUI Buttons in every application window with python

Tags: python, computer-vision, opencv, ocr

I want to detect every buttons in every application windows.
For example, in explorer window, I want to detect every Tags, folders, files and Buttons like "page back", "page forward", "Min", "Max" and "Close". how to solve it?

For it, I used tesseract OCR but It cannot detect them at once. How to improve of accuracy of tesseract OCR model?
Here is a code.

````py
import re
import cv2
import pytesseract
from pytesseract import Output

img = cv2.imread('invoice-sample.jpg')
d = pytesseract.image_to_data(img, output_type=Output.DICT)
keys = list(d.keys())

date_pattern = '^(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])/(0[1-9]|1[012])/(19|20)\d\d$'

n_boxes = len(d['text'])
for i in range(n_boxes):
    if int(d['conf'][i]) > 60:
        if re.match(date_pattern, d['text'][i]):
            (x, y, w, h) = (d['left'][i], d['top'][i], d['width'][i], d['height'][i])
            img = cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 2)

cv2.imshow('img', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```
````